# How to set pcolor savefig colorbar transparency

Tags: python, matplotlib, transparency, colorbar

I am trying to export a pcolor figure with a colorbar.
The cmap of the colorbar has a transparent color.
The exported figure has transparent colors in the axes but not in the colorbar. How can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

x = np.random.random((10, 10))
colors = [(0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1)]
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom', colors, N=256, gamma=0)
plt.pcolor(x,cmap=cm)
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('figure.pdf',transparent=True)
```

I put the image against a grey background to check. As can be seen, the cmap in the axes is transparent while the one in the colorbar is not.

[image: I put the image against a grey background to check. As can be seen, the cmap in the axes is transparent while the one in the colorbar is not]

Comment: Since transparent colors on white background do not appear transparent at all, what would you suggest to do with the generated pdf to see that issue?

Comment: See the attached figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the colorbar resides inside an axes, it has an additional background patch associated with it. This is white by default and will not be taken into account when `transparent=True` is used inside of `savefig`.

A solution is hence to remove the facecolor of this patch manually,

```
cb.patch.set_facecolor("none")
```

A complete example, which shows this without actually saving the figure

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

x = np.random.random((10, 10))
colors = [(1,1,1,0), (0,0,0,1)]
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom', colors, N=256, gamma=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor="grey")

im = ax.pcolor(x,cmap=cm)
cb = fig.colorbar(im, drawedges=False)

ax.set_facecolor("none")
cb.patch.set_facecolor("none")

plt.show()
```

[image]